# Earth's magnetic effect on my magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, earth

My magnet seems to work independently of, and unaffected by, the Earth's magnetic field, yet the magnetic field of my magnet changes as I introduce some other similar magnets of varied sizes into its field.

How would the magnetic field of this magnet differ at different locations on, orbiting around, and anywhere between, Earth and our other planets?